# Get Column Name(Header) of Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTable which is populated by Text data(in first column)and checkboxes in remaining columns and a submit button which on click should show the selected checkboxes column name and the text from first column.

I got the solution to display the text , but not for the column name..
Can you please help me to show Column name as well as the row text of all selected checkboxes..
thank you

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried till now ?